# Как ключи поставить на место значений в массиве

Tags: php

Есть метод который принимает через пост id. И записывает в сессию, потом делает массив где ключ это id, а значение это число ключей. Как сделать обычный массив, где ключи это 0,1,2,3 а значения это id

вот массив который делает сейчас

```
Array ( [25+43] => 5 [26+43] => 3 )
```

желаемый результат

```
Array ( [0] => 25+43 [1] => 26+43 )
```

метод:

```
public static function addProduct($id)
    {
        // Приводим $id к типу integer
        //$id = intval($id);

        // Пустой массив для товаров в корзине
        $productsInCart = array();

        // Если в корзине уже есть товары (они хранятся в сессии)
        if (isset($_SESSION['products'])) {
            // То заполним наш массив товарами
            $productsInCart = $_SESSION['products'];
        }

        // Проверяем есть ли уже такой товар в корзине
        if (array_key_exists($id, $productsInCart)) {
            // Если такой товар есть в корзине, но был добавлен еще раз, увеличим количество на 1
            $productsInCart[$id] ++;
        } else {
            // Если нет, добавляем id нового товара в корзину с количеством 1
            $productsInCart[$id] = 1;
        }

        // Записываем массив с товарами в сессию
        $_SESSION['products'] = $productsInCart;

        // Возвращаем количество товаров в корзине
        return self::countItems();
    }
```

Comment: Лучше покажите какой у вас массив (сторение)

Comment: @Arsen Показал)

Comment: Вы бы нагуглили ответ быстрее, чем в итоге писали вопрос. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-keys.php

Comment: [array_keys($array)](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-keys.php)

Comment: А если такое значение уже есть в массиве, что делать?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Вы имеете ввиду 2 одинаковых ключа?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Тогда придется еще целых 3 секунды погуглить. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php. И кстати да. Про ключи выше

Comment: Вы говорите, что Вы id хотите добавлять как значение. Здорово! А что делать, если такой id уже есть в массиве? Или пользователь не может добавить в корзину товар дважды?

Answer (score 0):

Для конеретого примера `$a = Array ( '[25+43]' => '5',  '[26+43]' => '3' );`

```
$a = array_flip($a);//меняет местами ключи и значения
$a = array_values($a);//оставляет значения с новыми ключами
```

получим

```
Array ( [0] => [25+43] [1] => [26+43] )
```